# ADB push multiple files with the same extension with a single command

Tags: android, push, adb

I want to push some files of the same type (`.img`) to the `/sdcard` partition of the phone with a single command. But the wildcard does not work:

```
adb push *.img /sdcard/
```

Is there any way I can achieve that?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Copy the `*.img` files to an empty directory, then push the directory (`adb push /tmp/images /storage/sdcard0`). `adb` will push all files in that directory to your designated location.

BTW, `/sdcard` as a path has been obsolete for quite some time, so please make sure you use a destination that exists and is supported by your device. Most Android 2.x/3.x/4.0 devices use `/mnt/sdcard`; Android 4.1 uses `/storage/sdcard0`.

Comment: Well I already did the "folder trick" but I was wondering if ADB supports wildcards.Hmm I never had a problem with /sdcard/ but I 've only used it on 4.1.1 (4.1.2 as of lately) in my Galaxy Nexus.Thanks a lot for answering!

Comment: @john: "I was wondering if ADB supports wildcards" -- it does not seem to.

Comment: In that case I am considering the folder trick you suggested as the answer.Thanks again!

Answer (score 22):

From my mind with echoing the file...

```
for i in *.img; do echo $i; adb push "$i" /sdcard/; done;
```

Comment: I believe that this could work (note that `/sdcard/` is obsolete, as the accepted answer suggests), but you should verify that it does and format your answer a little better.

Comment: @znt: I fixed it.

Answer (score 18):

Assuming you are using **Windows**, You can use a for loop to find files with an extension and do an adb push with that file like this in command line

```
for %i in (*.img) do adb push %i /sdcard/folderName/%i
```

If you are saving it as a batch file then make sure to add an extra "%" before "%i" like below

```
 for %%i in (*.img) do adb push %%i /sdcard/folderName/%%i
```

If you are using **GNU/Linux**, you can use this command which basically does the same thing

```
for f in *.img; do adb push $f /sdcard/folderName/$f; done
```

Hope it helped :)

Answer (score 4):

Using find (`{}` represents file name):

```
find *.img -exec adb push {} /storage/sdcard0 \;
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a script that does it (dash, Ubuntu Precise).

*mpush:*

```
#D=echo
D=
S=
if [ $1 == "-s" ]; then
    S="-s $2"
    shift
    shift
fi
if [ $# -lt 2 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 directory files..."
else
DIR=$1
shift
for f in $*
do
  #echo "Processing $DIR/$f file..."
  echo ~/aspt/adb ${S} push "$f" "$DIR/$f"
  ${D} ~/aspt/adb ${S} push "$f" "$DIR/$f"
done
fi
```

Usage:

```
mpush /sdcard/ libMyLib.so
mpush /sdcard/ libFirst.so libSecond.so
mpush /sdcard/ *
mpush -s 109d8a6fe0678a3 /sdcard/ *
```

The first two lines are left there for debugging: you can change the first two lines to

```
D=echo
#D=
```

and have the script print the `adb push` commands instead of executing them.

UPDATE: added ability to push to all attached devices (the `-all` switch)

```
#D=echo
D=
S=
if [ $1 == "-2all" -o $1 == "-all" ]; then
  shift
  DEVICES=`~/aspt/adb devices | tail -n +2 | awk '{print $1}'`
  if [ $# -lt 2 ]; then
      echo "Usage: $0 [options] directory files..."
      echo "Options:"
      echo "-s device-id -- push to the specified device"
      echo "-all or -2all -- push to all devices"
  else
    DIR=$1
    shift
    for d in $DEVICES
    do
      for f in $*
      do
    #echo "Processing $DIR/$f file..."
    echo ~/aspt/adb -s $d push "$f" "$DIR/$f"
    ${D} ~/aspt/adb -s $d push "$f" "$DIR/$f"
      done
    done
  fi
else
  if [ $1 == "-s" ]; then
      S="-s $2"
      shift
      shift
  fi
  if [ $# -lt 2 ]; then
      echo "Usage: $0 [options] directory files..."
      echo "Options:"
      echo "-s device-id -- push to the specified device"
      echo "-all or -2all -- push to all devices"
  else
    DIR=$1
    shift
    for f in $*
    do
      #echo "Processing $DIR/$f file..."
      echo ~/aspt/adb ${S} push "$f" "$DIR/$f"
      ${D} ~/aspt/adb ${S} push "$f" "$DIR/$f"
    done
  fi
fi
```